# How do I get CPU Clock Speed in C++ (Linux)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, cpu-speed

How can I get the CPU clock speed in C++?

I am running Ubuntu 9.10 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the pseudo-file `/proc/cpuinfo`. See [this link](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/en-US/Reference_Guide/s2-proc-cpuinfo.html) for an explanation of the fields it contains.

Comment: This is not the current CPU speed however. Or not always.

Comment: There are new links. For RHEL 4, the explanation is in the [Reference Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s2-proc-cpuinfo.html). For RHEL 6, the explanation is in the [Deployment Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-cpuinfo.html)

Answer (score 2):

This information is available in sysfs. In particular, check out `scaling_cur_freq` and `cpuinfo_cur_freq` in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq`.

Answer (score 1):

When I had a Compaq Athlon64 laptop, its /proc/cpuinfo always reported its maximum speed.

I only got reliable current frequency numbers from the files in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cpufreq`.

I suppose your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

try executing the command lscpu